# jQuery + PHP: Usar formularios con .ajax()

Tags: php, html, jquery, formularios

¿Es posible seguir utilizando la etiqueta `form` para un formulario de registro de usuarios cuando empleas `.ajax()`?

El proceso en sí lo hace un archivo `.php`; de hecho, anteriormente todo el registro estaba controlado por PHP, pero ahora con `.ajax()` me veo obligado a sustituir la etiqueta `form` por `div`, porque de lo contrario el proceso continua vía `POST` y se refresca automáticamente el navegador para mostrar el mensaje que corresponda en vez de aparecer en un modal (si no especifico `method` el proceso discurre vía `GET` y el comportamiento es aún peor, porque mi web vuelve al `index.php`).

El problema es que al no ser ya un `form` dejan de operar algunas funcionalidades HTML (como que se dé un mensaje de aviso si el tamaño mínimo del nombre o de la contraseña no llega a 3 caracteres) y una `promise` con `.trigger('reset')` que utilizaba para borrar los datos del formulario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba generando un objeto FormData para enviar todo el contenido del formulario
y en tu form agregar onsubmit="return false"

ejemplo:
enviar

```
<form id="idformulario" onSubmit="retun false">
<button id="idbotonsubmit">enviar<button>

</form>
    $(document).on('clic','#idbotonsubmit', function(){
        var data = new FormData(document.getElementById("idformulario"));
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'archivo.php',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,    
            data: data,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(res) {
               $('#idDiv').html(res);
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("fail");
            }
          });
    });
```

Comment: Esto es suficiente: `onSubmit="return false"`. Añadiendo esa cláusula a mi HTML todo funciona perfectamente sin tocar nada más. ¡Gracias!